# GWT show file chooser dialog

Tags: java, gwt

I am looking for a way to show a file chooser dialog box for the users of my GWT application. This file will not be uploaded to the server, so for this reason I cannot use the GWT FileUpload widget.

The goal is to have a button for a user to click, pop up the file chooser box, and the path to the file chosen gets saved to the database. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully, this is not possible.

If that was possible, it would be a huge security hole. A path to a file may reveal information that users are not interested in sharing, or information that hackers can use to choose the right attack.